# C++ std::filesystem::copy fail with "Network location cannot be reached"

Tags: c++, c++17, std-filesystem

I have written a small c++ application which is being automatically started after Windows boot on a couple of clients. This application will copy a file from a network share (same network share for all clients) to the local disk. When I reboot all clients at once, a bunch of them will get an error 1231 from the std::filesystem::copy function with following message:

> "Network location cannot be reached"

If I reboot all clients with an interval of a couple of seconds between them, then there is no problem.
This makes me think that the copy function might be blocking the file during copying.

Is there some setting that I am missing that prevents this? Is this normal behaviour?

EDIT: I have been able to fix the network problem, I now however get an error 32 which states that "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". Does the copy function lock the files that are currently being copied?

Comment: Sleep/Wait for complete initialization of Client before launch/start of your application.
ERROR_NETWORK_UNREACHABLE - 1231 (0x4CF) - Its network error on windows OS

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like the network share has not been mounted yet. If all clients attempt to mount the same network share at the same time this may mean a lot of work for the server handing out the share. Consequently, some clients may time out and may have to repeat their request. Make sure the network share is actually mounted before you attempt to copy from it.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a problem due to an uninitialized network of your client workstations.
The error ERROR_NETWORK_UNREACHABLE - 1231 (0x4CF) indicates that the path provided is not reachable at an instance.

You can use two approaches:

1) Continue with while-loop until you get the success to check whether filepath exists. Handle the error situation with try-catch if any.
When you get the success go for download/copy.

2) Sleep for 60 sec to 180 sec before download/copy file in the current program.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my question; there was indeed a problem with active directory where the client was not immediately given an IP address and thus not being able to access the share.
After some more testing, I now see that I am only able to perform a copy command on one of the clients using std::filesystem::copy, while the others show an error message 32, stating that "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". If I use the xcopy command in a batch file instead on all devices simultaneously, I do not get any error...